# is it possible to create an email only authentication from existing email-password structure in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to create email only authentication. Instead of having a login, I want a situation where I will only have signup and once the email is entered, a bearer token is created. 
I have the signup function and login function which worked when I had password initiated but I have removed the password but I tried to move the "create token" to signup. It gives error that token is undefined.

**Signup function**

```
public function signup(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
           'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users'
        ]);
        $user = new User([
            'email' => $request->email
        ]);
        $user->save();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully created user!'
        ], 201);
    }
```

Login function

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email'

        ]);
        $credentials = request(['email', '=']);
        if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);
        $user = $request->user();
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
        $token = $tokenResult->token;
        if ($request->remember_me)
            $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
        $token->save();
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
                $tokenResult->token->expires_at
            )->toDateTimeString()
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Google ["laraval email only authentication"](https://www.google.com/search?&q=laraval+email+only+authentication) seams has a few hits .. Also searching on stackoverflow ["Laravel email login"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Laravel+email+login) has found some.

Comment: Ok thank you let me try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really simple, you have already done most of the work needed to be done here. You don't need the login function rather you need to copy the token part of the function as illustrated below

```
 public function signup(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
           'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users'
        ]);
        $user = new User([

            'email' => $request->email
        ]);
         $user->save();
        Auth::login($user);
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
        $token = $tokenResult->token;
        if ($request->remember_me)
            $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
        $token->save();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully created user!',
            'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
                $tokenResult->token->expires_at
            )->toDateTimeString()
            ], 201);


    }
```